# MySql - Search in between two dates from a varchar

Tags: php, mysql

I have my query;

```
SELECT ID, 
REFERENCE, 
SHORT_NAME, 
TITLE, 
DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( NEXT_EVENT_DATE,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) AS NEXT_EVENT_DATE_FORMATTED 
  from cases WHERE `CLIENT_ID` = '54' 
  AND NEXT_EVENT_DATE_FORMATTED > '01/10/2014' 
  AND NEXT_EVENT_DATE_FORMATTED < '31/10/2016'
```

I am pushing data up through heterogeneous services which is why my date column is using a varchar and not an actual date field. What is the correct way to search between the first and last day of this month? (I will generate the where part using PHP most likely, unless mysql knows when the last day of the month is).

Thanks, Harry.

Comment: Is this the query that you're using? Where is the "WHERE" clause?

Comment: Fixed, it was an error when I was formatting the code for SO to make it easier to read, not in my source.

Comment: `WHERE ... AND YEAR(DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( NEXT_EVENT_DATE,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%d/%m/%Y' )) = YEAR(NOW())
AND MONTH( DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( NEXT_EVENT_DATE,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%d/%m/%Y' )) = MONTH(NOW())`

Comment: Mihai, that didn't work. I did some debugging and found that the following is null; `SELECT MONTH( DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(  "2012-07-16 00:00:00",  '%Y-%m-%d' ) ,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) )`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Regardless of what you wrote, the correct way is to use a proper time storage. You pushing data through services has nothing to do with storage choice for the date. If you want your database to help you get the data - you model it properly. I don't see why you can store `01/10/2014` but you can't store a proper datetime or even a timestamp (which are trivial to create from any format these days). Please don't be one of the army of "There is no way that I can code properly, I have to screw this up because of no reason."

Comment: Then might you suggest how to properly convert an oracle date type at the stage where the data is being pushed from Heterogeneous Services (12C database) please?